# Table mid align

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I have made two tables side by side as below.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|cc}
    \hline
    + & 0 & 1 \\
    \hline
    0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
    \hline
    1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{tabular}
\quad
\begin{tabular}{c|cc}
    \hline
    $\cdot$ & 0 & 1 \\
    \hline
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \hline
    1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

But the texts in each cell is aligned top. How do I align them all in the middle?

Thank you for your answer in advance.

Comment: I am confused. The text in each cell is not aligned to the top. Perhaps I am misunderstanding the question? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: They are in the in the middle. That is, on the baseline of each row.

Comment: The numbers appear to be "lifted" a bit and not in the center of their respective boxes?

Comment: That is just because the numbers have height but not depth i.e. there is nothing below the baseline. If you add a `y`, you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

The effect is the result of the numberals being lining and so having no depth. That is, there is nothing *below* the baseline. If you add a letter which has depth e.g. `y` and one with only height e.g. `f`, you can see that the content is aligned correctly (from TeX's point of view, at least) in terms of the baseline:

[image: basline variations]

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|cc}
    \hline
    + & 0 & 1fy \\
    \hline
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \hline
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{tabular}
\quad
\begin{tabular}{c|cc}
    \hline
    $\cdot$ & 0 & 1 \\
    \hline
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \hline
    1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

You might want to take a look at `booktabs` to improve the formatting. In general, `booktabs` recommends dispensing with vertical rules altogether. For example:

[image: alternative]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \toprule
    + & 0 & 1fy \\
    \midrule
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \midrule
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\quad
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \toprule
    $\cdot$ & 0 & 1 \\
    \midrule
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \midrule
    1 & 0 & 1 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Or look at one of the other packages available for enhanced tabular layouts. For example, here's a possibility using `makecell`:

[image: making cells]

Doubtless this is not the most efficient usage but I'm not very familiar with this package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\renewcommand\cellalign{cc}
\begin{tabular}{c|cc}
  \Xhline{1pt}
    + & \gape[t]{0} & \gape[t]{1} \\
    \hline
    \gape[t]{0} & \gape[t]{0} & \gape[t]{1} \\
    \hline
    \gape[t]{1} & \gape[t]{1} & 0 \\
    \Xhline{1pt}
\end{tabular}
\quad
\begin{tabular}{c|cc}
    \Xhline{1pt}
    $\cdot$ & \gape[t]{0} & \gape[t]{1} \\
    \hline
    \gape[t]{0} & \gape[t]{0} & \gape[t]{0} \\
    \hline
    \gape[t]{1} & \gape[t]{0} & \gape[t]{1} \\
    \Xhline{1pt}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```